Importing Client Certs into Firefox
Making an attempt to put some client certs into Firefox on Red Hat. I am attempting to do this at provision using puppet. Everything I looked into said to put the key.db and cert.db files into a /home/{user}/.mozilla/firefox/foo.default. My problem is that .default is not created until after the first time a user starts Firefox on the machine. Is there any good work around for this? I am almost tempted to run a firefox process as the required users and then kill it prior to attempting to stash the certs just to generate the appropriate default file.

Why couldn't your puppet code create the default folder just before writing the .db files?
